# Wordpress: How to insert a theme variable into a widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created some functions in my theme functions.php file, and I call the main function in the header.php file, and store the result into a variable, I want to use this value in a widget.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/

There are other plugins out there that do the same thing: allow execution of PHP in text widgets.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use variables declared in header.php inside the widget using this plugin.

Comment: Are you using global variables? By default, variables are limited to the function they are declared in.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

You can save variables such as theme options in the wp_options table.

To add set a value, use [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)  and to read that value, use [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option).

[add_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) can also be used but it works only if the variable doesn't exist in the database. Hence, update_option() is preferred.

Comment: The value is not the same on every page refresh, its returned from a function included in functions.php, that's mean I can't store it in the database

Answer (score 0):

In widget for get variable just use:

```
$variable=$GLOBALS['theme_variable'];
```